# Finding Shortest Path in Java - Dijkstra Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, dijkstra

Im working on a Dijkstra algorithm. I wrote this code but the `computePath()` method has a error in

```
for(Edge e:u.adjacencies){
```

I don't know what should I do.

```
        import java.util.PriorityQueue;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Collections;



public class DijkstraAlgo{

    public static void computePaths(Node source){
        source.shortestDistance=0;

        //implement a priority queue
        PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
        queue.add(source);

        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            Node u = queue.poll();

            /*visit the adjacencies, starting from 
            the nearest node(smallest shortestDistance)*/

        //First Error
for(Edge e:u.adjacencies){



                Node v = e.target;
                double weight = e.weight;

                //relax(u,v,weight)
                double distanceFromU = u.shortestDistance+weight;
                if(distanceFromU<v.shortestDistance){

                    /*remove v from queue for updating 
                    the shortestDistance value*/
                    queue.remove(v);
                    v.shortestDistance = distanceFromU;
                    v.parent = u;
                    queue.add(v);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Node> getShortestPathTo(Node target){

        //trace path from target to source
        List<Node> path = new ArrayList<Node>();
        for(Node node = target; node!=null; node = node.parent){
            path.add(node);
        }


        //reverse the order such that it will be from source to target
        Collections.reverse(path);

        return path;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args){

        //initialize the graph base on the Romania map
        Node n1 = new Node("VertexA");
        Node n2 = new Node("VertexB");
        Node n3 = new Node("VertexC");
        Node n4 = new Node("VertexD");
        Node n5 = new Node("VertexE");


        //initialize the edges
        n1.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(n2,8),
                new Edge(n3,2),

        };

        n2.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(n4,3),
                new Edge(n5,5)
        };

        n3.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(n4,4),

        };

        n4.adjacencies = new Edge[]{
                new Edge(n5,1),

        };



        Node[] nodes = {n1,n2,n3,n4,n5};

        //compute paths SECOND ERROR PART
        computePaths(n1);
        computePaths(n2);
        computePaths(n3);
        computePaths(n4);
        computePaths(n5);


        for(Node n: nodes){
            System.out.println("Distance to " + 
                n + ": " + n.shortestDistance);
            List<Node> path = getShortestPathTo(n);
            System.out.println("Path: " + path);
        }

        List<Node> path = getShortestPathTo(n3);
        System.out.println("Path: " + path);

    }


}


//define Node
class Node implements Comparable<Node>{

    public final String value;
    public Edge[] adjacencies;
    public double shortestDistance = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    public Node parent;

    public Node(String val){
        value = val;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return value;
    }

    public int compareTo(Node other){
        return Double.compare(shortestDistance, other.shortestDistance);
    }

}

//define Edge
class Edge{
    public final Node target;
    public final double weight;
    public Edge(Node targetNode, double weightVal){
        target = targetNode;
        weight = weightVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which error are you getting? Show us the exact error.

Comment: There are two steps involved in creating software. One is writing the code, The next is making it work. Start honing your debugging skills.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at DijkstraAlgo.computePaths(DijkstraAlgo.java:24)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, check [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/).

Comment: @lexicore Maybe he wants to implement this algorithm for learning purposes. Don't assume he just cares about the output.

Comment: @Gili Even in this case, JGraphT source code is worth looking at.